# Angular: after moving from Karma to Jest, Error "Unrecognized CLI Parameters"

Tags: angular, jestjs, jest-preset-angular

I updated my project from Angular 6.4 to Angular 7.1 and now running the script: `ng test app-name --coverage` gives me the error:

```
● Unrecognized CLI Parameters:

  Following options were not recognized:
  ["main", "polyfills", "tsConfig"]

  CLI Options Documentation:
  https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli.html
```

The configuration for the test command in angular.json looks like this:

```
"test": {
  "builder": "@angular-builders/jest:run",
  "options": {
    "main": "apps/app-name/src/test.ts",
    "polyfills": "apps/app-name/src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "apps/app-name/tsconfig.spec.json",
    "configPath": "./jest.config.json",
    "styles": [
      "apps/app-name/src/styles.scss"
    ],
    "scripts": [],
    "assets": [
      "apps/app-name/src/favicon.ico",
      "apps/app-name/src/assets"
    ]
  }
},
```

How am I supposed to update the config to be compatible with Angular 7?

Comment: Try using `--code-coverage` rather than `--coverage` when running the tests.

Comment: @R.Richards This way I get: `Unknown option: '--code-coverage'`. I don#t think the error is related to the coverage-flag. even without it I get the same error.

Comment: Do the unit tests run if you simply run `ng test`? No other parameters.

Comment: @R.Richards no it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was that I forgot to remove/replace the old karma-builder configuration when I moved to Jest.

Apparently Angular 7 checks things like that better than Angular 6 (hooray!), so I mistook it for an Angular or Jest bug.